# Write function using innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write function using **innerHTML** in **javascript**, like below :

*eg:*

```
frameDoc.body.innerHTML ='<script type="text/javascript">';
frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='function highlightSearch(){';
frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='alert("example");';
frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='return true;}';
frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='</script>';
```

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve by doing this- there aren't many situations this would be the _best_ way of doing things.

Comment: Or more neatly via document.createElement('script')

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to add a `function` to an `HTML` file trought `innerHTML`. In fact, most of the third parties `API` do so. They append their own script using this system or `document.createElement('script')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute the code you should change approach. The best way to do so is to create a dynamic script node and add it to the document. A worse approach but that still works is using document.write.

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
document.write('function highlightSearch(){');
document.write('alert("example");');
document.write('return true;}');
document.write('highlightSearch()');
document.write('<\/script>');
```

Note that I added document.write('highlightSearch()'); to execute the function.

Comment: Please suggest me by using innerHTML.

Comment: Instead of innerHTML, you can use appendChild. 
var g = document.createElement('script');
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.text = "alert(\"hi\");"
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);